# How do you nest dictionaries and point to specific keys in another dictionary

Tags: vb.net

So to begin  I have created 3 dictionaries properly nested within each other, I then add keys/values to the gdicRawItems dictionary without issue. Now I am adding a key to the gdicPreppedItems dictionary but I need it to point to multiple key/values in gdicRawItems, what is the proper syntax to do so? Essentially when I view the PreppedItems dictionary and look at the key "Cheesburger" I want to see the values as Beef Patty, Bun, and Cheese Slice

```
Public Class frmDishDesigner
Public gdicRawItems As New SortedDictionary(Of String, String)
Public gdicPreppedItems As New SortedDictionary(Of String, SortedDictionary(Of String, String))
Public gdicDishes As New SortedDictionary(Of String, SortedDictionary(Of String, SortedDictionary(Of String, String)))

Public Sub Main()

End Sub
Public Sub frmDishDesigner_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    gdicRawItems.Add("Beef Patty", "Beef Patty")
    gdicRawItems.Add("Cheese Slice", "Cheese Slice")
    gdicRawItems.Add("Bun", "Bun")
    gdicRawItems.Add("Water", "Water")
    gdicRawItems.Add("Potato", "Potato")
    gdicRawItems.Add("Mushroom", "Mushroom")
    gdicRawItems.Add("Plate", "Plate")

    gdicPreppedItems.Add("Cheesburger", (gdicRawItems.Item(Bun)))
    gdicPreppedItems.Add("
```

Comment: Wow... you need a database.

Comment: There are definitely better ways to do this, but this is the requirements of the project

Comment: Just to be clear, is this homework?

Comment: Yes it is, and I'm not looking for a solution to my project, just the proper syntax to assign the values from one dictionary to another

Comment: I'm trying to work around having to create several dictionaries and instead use the 3 base dictionaries created. In the other question I see your response for setting one dictionary equal to another but that's not what I'm trying to do here. Here I'm wondering how you set the value of a key in dic2 to that of a key in dic1. Essentially I want one of dic2's key's value to equal a certain key in dic1. Sorry for any confusion

Comment: I've accepted your answers. New to stack overflow, I'm assuming you get some sort of credit for having the best answer so credit given in that case.

Comment: @AdamCampbell You should update your question to describe what you're trying to achieve, not only what you did. I tried writing an answer for you since it seems a single dictionary should be enough for your problem but you don't have a problem description in your post and the code is confusing. The solution depends on what your requirements are - a single dictionary would work or you could use a dictionary that points to lists of common ingredients, etc.

Comment: Why are you trying to work around having to create several dictionaries?  Sure, there's some overhead, but until you get into the millions of items, it won't come close to hitting resource limits.  There's a famous quote from Knuth about premature optimization.  Start with the most natural organization for solving your problem, then optimize when you need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're approaching an example of when a database is necessary. You can use classes and lists, but this is being built at design time, and if you ever want to change the recipe you will need to recompile your code:

```vb
Public Class PreppedItem
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property RawIngredients As New List(Of String)
End Class

Public Class Dish
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property PreppedItems As New List(Of PreppedItem)
End Class
```

```vb
Dim cheeseburgerDish As New Dish() With {
    .Name = "Cheeseburger Dish",
    .PreppedItems = New List(Of PreppedItem) From {
        New PreppedItem() With {.Name = "Cheeseburger",
            .RawIngredients = New List(Of String) From {"Beef Patty", "Cheese Slice", "Bun"}
        },
        New PreppedItem() With {.Name = "Fries",
            .RawIngredients = New List(Of String) From {"Potato"}
        }
    }
}
```

Using your types, you can create one dish, but it will break when you try to add another dish. Because the dish holds the prepped items dictionary, but if you add to that for the next dish, then it will also add for the first dish. So it's impossible with your design.

```vb
gdicRawItems.Add("Beef Patty", "Beef Patty")
gdicRawItems.Add("Cheese Slice", "Cheese Slice")
gdicRawItems.Add("Bun", "Bun")
gdicRawItems.Add("Water", "Water")
gdicRawItems.Add("Potato", "Potato")
gdicRawItems.Add("Mushroom", "Mushroom")
gdicRawItems.Add("Plate", "Plate")

Dim cheeseBurger = New SortedDictionary(Of String, String)
cheeseBurger.Add("Bun", gdicRawItems("Bun"))
cheeseBurger.Add("Beef Patty", gdicRawItems("Beef Patty"))
cheeseBurger.Add("Cheese Slice", gdicRawItems("Cheese Slice"))

Dim fries = New SortedDictionary(Of String, String)
fries.Add("Potato", gdicRawItems("Potato"))

gdicPreppedItems.Add("Cheeseburger", cheeseBurger)
gdicPreppedItems.Add("Fries", fries)

gdicDishes.Add("Cheeseburger Dish", gdicPreppedItems)
```

If using a database, you can design it as such. Gives you an idea of what you would want to do.

Ingredient

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Beef Patty |
| 2 | Cheese Slice |
| 3 | Bun |
| 4 | Water |
| 5 | Potato |
| 6 | Mushroom |
| 7 | Plate |

PreppedItem

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Cheeseburger |
| 2 | Fries |
| 3 | Mushroom Burger |
| 4 | Hamburger |

PreppedItemIngredient

| ID | PreppedItemID | IngredientID | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 | 5 | 1 |
| 5 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 6 | 3 | 6 | 1 |
| 7 | 3 | 3 | 2 |
| 8 | 4 | 1 | 1 |
| 9 | 4 | 3 | 2 |

Plate

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Cheeseburger Plate |
| 2 | Mushroom Burger Plate |

PlatePreppedItem

| ID | PlateID | PreppedItemID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 |

Now to change a recipe you just change the database, not your code. There is a lot more you could do here as to quantities and units of measure, but this is a basic description.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it the way you want. You must add a dictionary, but you only have one dictionary for all raw ingredients.

```vb
gdicPreppedItems.Add("Cheesburger", gdicRawItems)
```

This will add all raw items.

Comment: That's 100% what I thought before even posting this question, but it gives me an error (BC30311: Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'SortedDictionary(Of String, String)' Any ideas?

Comment: You're right. Actually my answer is wrong. Is your instructor trying to lead you to the logic conclusion of using databases?

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how I would proceed then? I could create several dictionaries but that seems very inefficient if the user were to add a large number of prepped items.

Comment: You may wish to read up on the Builder Pattern.